# Rearchitecting procedural PHP

Tags: php, frameworks

I need to re-architect a PHP application that is entirely procedural. Pretty much every WTF-ism you can ever think of is in this which means that it's likely to be more of a rewrite than anything else.

I want to stagger this and would like to do it with MVC.

Can anyone recommend a PHP framework that is going to help me?

The current database (MySQL) is OK - but the code isn't.

Some updates:
* I consider myself to be very skilled in web programming but I do very little in PHP
* A lot of experience in MVC
* No issues with Design Patterns
* The project is an ecommerce platform
* I am coming from a mainly .NET background

Comment: Depends on your skills in OOP, Design pattern + type of projet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [CodeIgniter](http://www.CodeIgniter.com). It's fast, stable and easy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

I use Codeigniter pretty much all time. It's quite easy to use and it has a light footstep (it loads only classes you use).

Answer (score 1):

[CakePHP 2.0 beta](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/zipball/2.0.0-beta) has pretty much everything you'd want in a framework. It's fast and it's really good once you've picked it up.

Comment: ONCE, you've picked it up :) +1

Answer (score 1):

```
If you have previous experience in Ruby on Rails => Yii
Else if you have previous experience in Django/Spring => Symfony2
Else if you have no experience in any framework & fast way learnig => CodeIgniter
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter is probably the simplest answer. It's easy to learn and well documented.  However, I prefer Zend Framework because of the templating system, the extensive library, and the new ZF tool.  However I found the learning curve on ZF to be a tad steep.  I recommend getting a CURRENT book to learn ZF.  "Easy PHP Web Sites with Zend Framework" is very good.

http://www.wjgilmore.com/books/read/easy_php_websites_with_the_zend_framework

Answer (score -1):

if you want other decision it's symfony(herder) or Yii(very easy to learn).
Simple project are creating by using(CI), if you project is harder use symphony or Yii.
If you want became ninja FrameworkDev learn Zend